# not able to continue in docker build

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to build an image using docker but if I made some changes and build it again then it starts from the beginning. Excepting it to continue from the line I have made changes.

```
sudo docker build -t flask-app .
```

I don't know why but it is not using cache

**Update**

example Initial dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

#working dir
WORKDIR /app

#copying content
COPY . /app

#Requirement installation
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Command to execute
CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

Later dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

#working dir
WORKDIR /app

#copying content
COPY . /app

#Requirement installation
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000

#Command to execute
CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

Expecting it know continue from Expose 8000 but it continues from beginning
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: We don't know either, since you did not supply any details.

Comment: @KlausD. I have added more details hope this helps you to understand the problem. if you require any other detail please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The COPY Command#**

Use `COPY . /app` after requirement installation, because Dockerfile is also included in this and will be copied to /app.

The COPY command in a Dockerfile allows you to import one or more external files into a Docker image. The COPY commands always get executed in order to have the latest version of the external file.

If the contents of all external files on the first COPY command are the same, the layer cache will be used and all subsequent commands until the next ADD or COPY command will use the layer cache.

However, if the contents of one or more external files are different, then all subsequent commands will be executed without using the layer cache.

In order to take advantage of Layer Caching in Docker you should structure your Dockerfile in a way that frequently changing steps such as COPY to be located towards the end of the Dockerfile file. This will ensure that the steps concerned with doing the same action are not unnecessarily rebuilt.

**For more info**
https://docs.semaphoreci.com/ci-cd-environment/docker-layer-caching/

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY . /app
```

If there's *any* ever so slight change in the context you pass in, then this step will get reevaluated. It can be worth it to only copy `requirements.txt` first, then install the dependencies from it, then copy the rest, to use the cache effectively.